# Программа на Python non stop

Tags: python, база-данных, парсер

Есть скрипт на Python. Его функционал: парсит веб страницу, из всего текста на той самой странице берет лишь номера телефонов и засовывает их в бд `PostgreSQL`.

Раз в сутки на веб странице добавляют новый текст. Ссылка не меняется, парсер работает по одной ссылке: `https://www.rttnews.com/CorpInfo/ConferenceCalls.aspx`.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы прога работала 24/7. Например я в 2 часа ночи её запустил, пк не выключаю, прога парсит сайт и затем повтораяет тоже самое через 24 часа. Повторюсь: пк не выключаю, работает 24 часа в сутки.

Как записать это в скрипте на Python, чтобы прогала сама раз в 24 часа повторяла процедуру парсинга? Здесь нужен `time.sleep`, а какой цикл?

Comment: Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

class Parser():    
        def __init__(self):
              pass
while True:
    time.sleep(1800)  # Каждый полчаса цикл будет повторятся
    if datetime.now().time().hour == 23:  # Вместо 23 указывешь свое время!
        pars = Parser()# Твой парсер
    else:
        print(datetime.now().time().hour)
```

Comment: @Илья не за что.Можно вместо класса написать функцию.Все зависит от сложности парсера.А так, можете воспользоваться моим примером и весь код засунуть в класс.

Comment: @Илья Поищите в интернете статьи на тему парсинга на python -они помогут намного больше, нежели мы здесь,в комментариях.

Интересные статьи(парсинг):

 https://proglib.io/p/parsing-course
 https://python-scripts.com/requests-rules

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос 24*60*60=86400.

Однако, на мой взгляд это не очень хорошая идея.  Как и любое повторение через достаточно большой промежуток времени. Дело не в том, что вы комп не выключаете, у вас еще и постоянно должен работать интерпретатор Python. Зачем?
В любой ОС есть планировщик задания. Настраиваете его так, что-бы раз в 24 часа запускался Python c указанием на выполняемый скрипт.
По крайней мере загрузка системы будет существенно меньше.

Кстати, именно для таких задач планировщики и предназначены.